# How to expand main UI elements on QT Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm testing a GUI for a python app through QT Designer and so far, it looks what I wanted it to look like: the four push buttons organized in a column at he left side and in the right side, a map with five radio buttons over it.

Here's a look of the main window:

[image: Here's a look of the main window.]

However, as I previewed the window and stretched/maximized it, the UI elements didn't expand. Instead, they all remained in the top left of the window. Is there anyway to fix this?

I was recommended to use layouts by isnerting two vertical layouts in one horizontal layouts, although for some reason, I couldn't stick the radio buttons inside the map image. Not to mention the elments were all spaced out. Not sure if there's an alternative to this by changing the code in python. Here's a look of the objects from the Main Window, in case that maybe I used them wrong.

[image: objects from the Main Window]

Comment: Please read more about [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and how to [use them in Designer](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html). Each item that shows that small red "forbidden" icon indicates that that widget has no proper layout set. Each container widget should have a proper top layout (set using the context menu), the layouts in the widget box are only intended for *nested* layouts, children of a top layout.